# read an Excel file embedded in a website

Tags: r, excel

I would like to read automatically in R the file which is located at

https://clients.rte-france.com/servlets/IndispoProdServlet?annee=2017

This link generates the automatic download of a zipfile. This zipfile contains the Excel file I want to read in R.

Does any of you have any suggestions on this? Thanks.

Comment: Search for [download.file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html). There are several dozen SO questions about downloading. Just make sure you use `wb` (binary) as the download mode

Comment: Thanks. I managed with "download.file("https://clients.rte-france.com/servlets/IndispoProdServlet?annee=2017", dest="dataset.zip", mode="wb")
unzip ("dataset.zip")" . The problem now is that this is an Excel 97 format and I cant manage to read it in R with regular readxl..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panagiotis' comment to use `download.file()` is generally good advice, but I couldn't make it work here (and would be curious to know why). Instead I used `httr`.
*(Edit: got it, I reversed args of `download.file()`... Repeat after me: always use named args...)*

Another problem with this data: it appears not to be a regular `xls` file, I couldn't open it with the yet excellent `readxl` package.
Looks like a tab separated flat file, but no success with `read.table()` either. `readr::read_delim()` made it.

```
library(httr)
library(readr)
r <- GET("https://clients.rte-france.com/servlets/IndispoProdServlet?annee=2017")
# Write the archive on disk
writeBin(r$content, "./data/rte_data")
rte_data <- 
  read_delim(
    unzip("./data/rte_data", exdir = "./data/"),
    delim = "\t",
    locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"),
    col_names = TRUE
  )
```

There still are parsing problems, but not sure they should be dealt with in this SO question.

Comment: A lot of sites fake Excel exports by sending a plain-old CSV or worse, an HTML table with a fake extension and content type. Which is extremely lazy, since `xlsx` (the only supported format) is just zipped XML files and therefore a lot *smaller* than the text files. There are a lot of libraries, packages etc that generate `.xlsx` files directly and are actually *easier* to use than generating CSVs but .... intellectual laziness